# ReactJS SetState in Recursive $.getJson

Tags: jquery, reactjs, recursion

I'm trying to get the result from a call and set it in state but it doesn't worked and I don't see why:

```
onButtonClick() {
 this.setState({Data: call(id, token)});
}


function call(Id, Token){
  var brand = Id;
  ReportTitle = brand;
  url = base_url + brand + "/posts?access_token=" + Token + request;
  var hasnext = true;
  return getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot(url, 0, finalJson);
}
```

In this function I do a recursive call in the $.getJSON.

```
function getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot(urlToCall, cnt, jsonData){
  var jsonFinalObject = '';
  $.getJSON(urlToCall).done(function(data) {
      var tempJson = {};
      tempJson = jsonData.concat(data.data);
      jsonData = tempJson;
      cnt++;
      if(data.paging.next != "" && cnt < 2){
        getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot(data.paging.next, compteur, jsonData);
      } else {        
        return JSON.stringify(jsonData);
      }
  });
}
```

But each time it return '', I tried to put .bind(this) at the end of the $.getJson and do the setState inside but it doesn't work. I tried in first with my functions (except onbuttonclick) in another file.js, then I tried with these functions in the component.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Can you add the complete code of your component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with the help of the answer of Max i found the solution:

```
handleResponse(data, context) {
  // bind this in your constructor.
  context.setState({ Data: data });
}

onClick() {
  var brand = Id;
  ReportTitle = brand;
  url = base_url + brand + "/posts?access_token=" + Token + request;
  var hasnext = true;
  getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot(url, 0, finalJson, this);
}

getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot(urlToCall, cnt, jsonData, context){
  var jsonFinalObject = '';
  $.getJSON(urlToCall).done(function(data) {
    var tempJson = {};
    tempJson = jsonData.concat(data.data);
    jsonData = tempJson;
    cnt++;
    if(data.paging.next != "" && cnt < 2){
      getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot(data.paging.next, compteur, jsonData);
    } else {        
      context.handleResponse(jsonData, context);
    }
 }.bind(this));
}
```

The solution was to add .bind(this) and pass "this" in getNextAnd... function for having the context for handleResponse AND setState.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return data from `.done` because `.done` returns a Promise. You should pass a callback that sets the state to `getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot` and invoke it in the `.done`.

```
handleResponse(data) {
  // bind this in your constructor.
  this.setState({ Data: data });
}

onClick() {
  var brand = Id;
  ReportTitle = brand;
  url = base_url + brand + "/posts?access_token=" + Token + request;
  var hasnext = true;
  getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot(url, 0, finalJson, this.handleResponse);
}

function getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot(urlToCall, cnt, jsonData, handleResponse){
  var jsonFinalObject = '';
  $.getJSON(urlToCall).done(function(data) {
    var tempJson = {};
    tempJson = jsonData.concat(data.data);
    jsonData = tempJson;
    cnt++;
    if(data.paging.next != "" && cnt < 2){
      getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot(data.paging.next, compteur, jsonData);
    } else {        
      handleResponse(jsonData);
    }
 });
}
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: Thanks you, i'll try it on tuesday and if it works i'll accept you're answer.

Comment: I tried you way and i doesn't worked.
It tells me: Unexpected token after the function.
Then i tried to remove "function" and put this.getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot in the both functions.
But when i call getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot in getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot it tells me that this.getNextAndConcatJSonOrNot is not a function.